# What is the difference between memtest86 and memtester?

Tags: memory, test

Memtest86+ - http://www.memtest.org

Memtester - http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/

I am looking at above memory test tools.

What is the difference between these two?
(In what aspect should it be used differently?)

Answer (score 4):

memorytester run on OS, so use api of OS for allocate ram and test it.
Memtest86 run without OS and is very small and access to RAM directly.

I always used Memtest86 I think is better, and more accurate for test RAM

Comment: Could you explain more about the accuracies of these tools?